# Can I fit a dbRDA model on a dataset that has the same continuous explanatory variable measurement in different samples?

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis

Can I fit a dbRDA on the following dataset:

```
CommunityData.distance <- matrix(c(0.58,0,0,0,0,0,0.26,0.20,0,0,0,0,0.64,0.21,0.22,0,0,0,0.18,0.40,0.91,0.78,0,0,0.37,0.23,0.68,0.91,0.25,0,0.86,0.25,0.92, 0.85,0.74,0.36), nrow=6, ncol=6, byrow = TRUE)

Envdata <- data.frame(Plot = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), Temperature = c(0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 2.5, 2.5), Species = c(A, B, A, B, A, B))

dbRDA <- capscale(CommunityData.distance <- Species + Temperature, data=Envdata)
```

I am primarily concerned about the repeated measure of temperature for two different samples.

Answer (score 1):

This is fine; temperature won't be able to account for (model) any of the within-plot variation in the data, only the between-plot variation, because the data are constant within and only vary between plots.

You can't include `plot` and `temperature` in the model as explanatory effects nor can you control for one variable and then try to estimate the effect of the other. `plot` and `temperature` are the same data, just rescaled. You could force differences say by treating `temperature` as linear but including `plot` as a factor as the factor representation of `plot` (by two additional variables on top of the intercept compared with one additional parameter if you treat `temperature` as linear).

You should now probably use the `dbrda()` in {vegan} to fit this model, in place of `capscale()`.